# How to calculate amp for a power supply?

Tags: power-supply, amperage

I know zilch about electrics.

Basically we have a power supply that my cousin has, and for some reason she wants to know what the amp is. The information I'm being given is:

> INPUT: 230V~AC 50Hz 100mA
>
> OUTPUT: 9v~AC 900mA 8.1VA

I don't know what this means. Can one of you kindly tell me what the amp is? I've Googled but we don't understand the jargon.

**Edit: the power supply is for a regular alarm clock and it's meant for use with UK electrical outlets if that helps. As far as I'm aware, 230V is standard and safe in the UK. My cousin just told me she's using an extension lead with 4 power outlets and it'll take a total of 13 amps safely. She already has a couple of other things plugged into it. She wants to know the amps of the alarm clock to be sure it's safe to plug into her extension.**

TIA

Comment: mA stands for milli-Ampere (thousandth of an Ampere)

Comment: @cornishninja - It would help if you can ask your cousin to explain _why_ she wants to "know what the amp is" - just to make sure that readers will be answering the right question. As Nick has highlighted, with those details you gave, two answers seem fairly obvious - _but_ perhaps your cousin is asking because she is blowing fuses (for example) which would lead to _different_ answers. So it's best find out _why_ she is asking!

Comment: If you are worried about the 13 Amp rating, you'd better investigate the other four outlets. A properly behaving alarm clock power supply shouldn't make much difference.

Answer (score 4):

Please pass this on.

Dear cousin,

The power supply is converting power from one voltage to another. The relationship between power, voltage and current is given by the formula \$ P = VI \$, where *P* is power in watts (W), *V* is voltage (V) and *I* is current (amperes, amps or A).

If we step down the voltage from 230 V to 9 V, a factor of about 25, then we would expect the current on the high voltage side to be 1/25 of that on the low-voltage side. The label says it will supply 900 mA (0.9 A) so input current should be about \$ \frac {900}{25} = 36~mA \$.

The manufacturers have specified that it could draw up to 100 mA on the input (from your wall socket). That means that one or more of the following is true:

1. The power supply is very inefficient (giving out only 36% of what it takes in).
2. The manufacturer has recorded the switch-on surge current. This would be very brief.
3. They've just picked the nearest standard fuse value above their required input.

Who knows?

Signed,

Transistor.

Comment: Just to be sure it's clear to me:you reffered to Pin=Pout.You didn't trust the manufacturer's input current spec...and you calculated the proportional input current without losses.Why does the voltage ratio apply to the amperage,too?

Comment: A lossless power supply would draw in the amount of power that it is being asked to supply. \$ V_{IN}\cdot I_{IN} = V_{OUT} \cdot I_{OUT} \$ so if we step down the voltage then, for a given power, the current must step up. High voltage power transmission is used because very high powers can be transmitted at low currents thus allowing smaller cables.